# summarizing multiple variables in group by

Tags: r, plyr, summarize

I need to find the mean of a variable and the number of times a particular combination occurs for that mean value in r.

In the example I have grouped by variables `cli`, `cus` and `ron` and need to summarize to find the mean of `age` and frequency of `cash` for this combination:

```
df%>% group_by(.dots=c("cli","cus","ron")) %>% summarise_all(mean(age),length(cash))
```

This doesn't work; is there another way out?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you

Comment: That's not how `summarise_all` works.

Answer (score 0):

may be it is just me as I seemed to have just over complicated this one,  just summarise gets me what I needed
df%>% group_by(.dots=c("cli","cus","ron")) %>% summarise(mean(age),length(cash))